# Duplicated in contenteditable div when jquery scroll down

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I use jQuery to autoload posts  when scroll-down and also use emojiarea jQuery to add smiles to comments on this posts that is like facebook posts and comments. The problem happen when scroll down I found more than textarea appears with eomtions button

The following code for add emojiarea in the page included to autoload more posts when scroll-down

**jQuery Code**

```
$('.emojis-plain').emojiarea({
  wysiwyg: false
});

var $wysiwyg = $('.emojis-wysiwyg').emojiarea({
  wysiwyg: true
});
var $wysiwyg_value = $('#emojis-wysiwyg-value');

$wysiwyg.on('change', function() {
  $wysiwyg_value.text($(this).val());
});
$wysiwyg.trigger('change');
```

when I click inspect Element I found 2 or 3 or 4 duplicated from next code for every post

```
<div class="emoji-wysiwyg-editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

I wnat this div aprear just one time for every post when I scroll down

any Help Appricated

Comment: How many elements of the class `emojis-plain` are on each post? Because you create an emojiarea for each of them.

Comment: I delete the part which use this class it is for normal textarea without smilies